# Android: Could not see the item in ListView if i didnt click on it

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hello I have a listview with a list of item but however when i run the application, I could not see the list of item in my listview unless i click on the listview itself. How do i ensure i could see the items even if i did not click on it?

My listview xml:

```
 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/nameListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"

    </ListView>
```

Comment: change `textColor` and change `android:listSelector` colors

Comment: Check your list text color and layout background color same (Black)

Comment: Call notifyDataSetChanged() on your Adapter. ya check @MdAbdulGafur answer

Comment: Post your adapter class

Comment: @SimplePlan My background is white and my text color is set black already but still i could not see it.

Comment: ok fine then post your all code then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just Remove the background And these three and run your program ...
Your code...

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nameListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent">

</ListView>
```

Change...

```
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nameListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"  >       

</ListView>
```

Comment: But if i remove my background it would be in black color. How can i go about if i want my background to be white?

Comment: You just go for custom List Adapter If you want Know that custom adapter Means i will put answer about that

Comment: You want to get the white background means You have to change the Theme in your Manifest File like this ... android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"   add this lines into your Application

Answer (score 0):

listview does not take textcolor. You can change the background color of listview from white to any other color or make custom listview